# How do I allow numbers in htaccess rewrite rule?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a htaccess setup like so:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z_]+)$ profile.php?name=$1 [NC,B,QSA]
```

it works fine however it doesn't work when the parameter has a number in it.

also is it possible to allow periods and commas?

What can I change?

Answer (score 3):

Change the regex:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z_]+)$ profile.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

OR even better

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ profile.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Since `\w` is same as `[0-9A-Za-z_]`

#### OP's comment:

> `is there a way to let it use periods and commas as well?`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w,.]+)/?$ profile.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: thanks. is there a way to let it use periods and commas as well?

Comment: awesome. it doesn't seem to work for this one though: 

RewriteRule ^([\w,.]+)/photos$ photos.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: heres my htaccess file. I can go to the profile url. but photos, yearbook, friends, tickets and upload all go to the profile url. The url at the top changes but it stays on the profile page.

http://pastebin.com/qhVph7qe

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41623/discussion-between-user2570937-and-anubhava)

Comment: There is no rule there that can cause URL to change, since you aren't using R flag.